# Issue when trying to populate a drop-down with database values

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am using the following HTML to show a selected drop down with values from the database and rest of the others in the list. It shows the selected name correctly but the selected is also displayed in the list.

How to remove the second time show selected name in the drop down list? Is this a good way to use drop down menu? Here Jobcategory and Jobdetails are associated.

Im using Laravel 4.2 and this is the HTML:

// view drop down form to save data

```
<div class="large-6 columns">
 <label>Job Category
    <select name="category[]">
    <option value="">Select Category</option>
    @foreach(JobCategory::all() as $jcat)
    <option value="{{ $jcat->id }}">{{ $jcat->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
    </select>
 </label>
</div>
```

// Edit drop down form to update the selected value

```
 <div class="large-6 columns">
 <label>Job Category
 <select name="category[]">
 <option value="{{$jobedit->jobcategory->id}}">{{$jobedit->jobcategory->name </option>
 @foreach(JobCategory::all() as $jcat)
 <option value="{{ $jcat->id }}">{{ $jcat->name }}</option>
 @endforeach
 </select>  
 </label>
 </div>
```

// database table for jobcategories

```
id | name
1  | Accounting/Finance
2  | Advertisement/Event Mgt.
3  | .....
```

// after save into jobdetails table

```
id | jobcategory_id | .......
1  |   5            | ...
```

I can retrieve the value of jobcategory in the edit form but it shows twice one in the selected value and other in the listed value of all jobcategory. This is the problem and i want only show the selected value and then rest of the others from jobcategory table without duplicate value of selected in the drop down. plz help.

// controller to to edit

```
public function getJobEdit($id)
{
    $jobedit = JobDetail::find($id);
    return View::make('employers.edit_single_jobs')->with('jobedit', $jobedit);
}
```

// JobDetail --model

```
public function jobcategory()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('JobCategory');
}
```

// JobCategory --model

```
public function jobdetails()
{
    return $this->hasMany('JobDetail', 'jobcategories');
}
```

Comment: laravel is provide a from_select from helper using that u can easily manage that like `{!! Form::select('cities_id', $citys, Input::old('cityes_id'),array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}`

Comment: What is in `{{ $cat->category_name }}` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Forms & HTML](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#drop-down-lists) helper of laravel.

#### Generating A Drop-Down List With Selected Default

```php
echo Form::select('size', array('L' => 'Large', 'S' => 'Small'), 'S');
```

where the first argument is the name of the `select` box. The second argument is an array of all entries in the box and the last argument determines which of the array elements is the selected one.

in your case it could look something like this:

```
{{ Form::select(
    'categoryName', 
    array(
        'Accounting/Finance'       => 'Accounting/Finance', 
        'Advertisement/Event Mgt.' => 'Advertisement/Event Mgt.',
        // to be continued ...
    ),
    '$cat->category_name'
); }}
```

//Edit

```
<div class="large-6 columns">
<label>Job Category
{{ Form::select('category[]', ['' => 'Select a category'] + $all_categories, $jobedit->jobcategory->id) }}
</select>  
</label>
</div>
```

where `$all_categories` should be an array of all categories as in the first example. You can get this from `JobCategory::all()`.

Comment: i tried and it worked but my question is the selected item shows in the menu  nicely but it also shows in the list menu also. I just want only one time show in the menu. Pls consider this to edit the menu. @Peh

Comment: Sorry then give us more input (edit your original question). The answer I posted doesn't list any item twice unless you put it into the array twice. Please give us more information about what you are doing otherwise we can't help.

Comment: yes this is because you didn't use the `Form::select` helper for your edit drop down menu as I suggested in my answer. Use it and your double entry is gone.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I set up drop-downs in my projects. I prepare the data in my controller (you'd obviously need a route and controller set up for this, I'm assuming you've done that):

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $categories = \Category::lists('name', 'id')->orderBy('name'); // assuming you have a Category model

    view('categories', compact('categories'));
}
```

Then you can use the Forms and HTML helper as Peh mentioned, this isn't available as a default in Laravel 5 so you'd need to add it into your project using composer. To do so either run `composer install illuminate/html` or add `"illuminate/html": "~5.0"` to your `composer.json` file and then run composer install. You'd then need to add `'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider'` to `config/app.php` in the `providers` array then add `'Form' => 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade'` and `'HTML'  => 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade'` to the `aliases` array in the same file. Once that's sorted you can use the Form and HTML helper in your view, as so:

**View**

```
{{ Form::select('categoryName', ['' => 'Select a category'] + $categories) }}
```

Your view would need to be saved as `filename.blade.php` if using the handlebars, otherwise `echo` it within `<?php ?>` tags.

Hope that helps you on your way.

Comment: but i need to show the selected default file in drop down menu in order to edit the drop down.  @haakym

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. By default file do you mean default option? If you want a default selected option put the option value as the third argument of the `Form::select()` function.